# How to delete text breaking after formulas inside enumerations

Tags: context

I'm using custom enumerations in ConTeXt and I include formulas, tables and the like. However, an itching issue is the breaking before a `\startformula ... \stopformula`. My MWE:

```
\defineenumeration[foo][alternative=serried,width=fit]
\starttext
\startfoo %\inframed{I don't want this space to be here}
\placeformula[hello]
\startformula
e^{i\pi}=-1
\stopformula 
\stopfoo 
\startfoo
Hola 
\stopfoo 
\stoptext
```

[image]
Options such as `alternative=margin` don't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you trying to achieve contradict the concept of displayed equations, but you can still do it.  Just place `\blank[overlay]` before the formula.

```
\defineenumeration[foo][alternative=serried,width=fit]
\starttext

\startfoo
    \blank[overlay]
    \placeformula[hello]
    \startformula
        e^{i\pi}=-1
    \stopformula 
\stopfoo 

\startfoo
    Hola 
\stopfoo 

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: (+1 for the solution). About the contradiction: I've seen it recommended to have the formula in the same line if what is before is short (in an old Swedish typesetting guide, I admit). See it in practice [in this article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889413), first line of the proof of Theorem 1.1.2 (fourth page in the pdf) and equation (1.2.3) (seventh page).